# How to search for a range in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Firebase Database there is the following data:

30XX,
31XX,
32XX,
33XX,
34XX,
35XX

Currently, I'm searching for an entry like this:

```
final Query query = FirebasePaths.usersRef()
                .orderByChild(Keys.Meta + '/' + index)
                .startAt(value)
                .limitToFirst(FirebaseDefines.NumberOfUserToLoadForIndex);
```

Now I want to conduct a search that goes from a range like 32XX to 34XX.
If I only had the numbers and not the "XX" in my database, I could search for a range by simply adding .endAt(...).

However, how can I search for a range of numbers when I've got the "XX" appended?

Answer (score 1):

If your 30XX range is strictly defined to never go outside the values from 3000 to 3099, then you can search just that range by using `startAt(3000)` and `endAt(3099)`.  The start and end values don't have to exist in the database in order to be used in a range query.